One number placed in 3 places makes these equations correct
Three equations

Text Version
8 = 4
9 = 27
16 = 64
Make all the 3 equations correct by adding a (same) number in 3 places. It must be the same exact number. This number (in 3 places) is the only thing that can be used in the final answer.

The number is

 1.5

Used like so

 8 = $4^{1.5}$

$9^{1.5}$ = 27

$16^{1.5}$ = 64

all equations are correct, and we only added the number

Perfectly done!

You could also use 2/3.

We can add

⅔

in 3 creative ways:

$$\begin{aligned}8&=\underset{\displaystyle3}{\underline2}{\underline4}\\9^2\!/_3&=27\\16&=6\frac234\end{aligned}$$


That last one is especially maddening! +1

Very creative and impressive! +1

Relies on bad notation though.

This is particularly great because the same number can be placed as an exponent on each of the larger numbers to make it work. When I opened the first spoiler, I thought, "Yeah, it's the reciprocal of the accepted answer and can be used in the same way," ...and then I opened the second spoiler.

The number is

 1

And as an extra challenge, I've placed it in exactly the same location for each equation!




Way to think outside the box.

this makes them inequations, not equations...

@MooNTreeS Ah, but the question says the solution makes the equations correct, not that it makes them correct equations.  It's kind of like making a caterpillar into a butterfly.

I'll concede it
